# Add setup steps for all tests in directory without adding in each suite

Tags: python, robotframework

I'd like to add some common keywords in every test suite setup. But as for me, it is not good practice to write same things in each suite.

I tried to use pre-run modifier, but not sure that it's possible to use it in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an initialization file. In this file you can specify your Suite Setup. It will be applied to all the testsuites in the same folder where the initialization file is placed. See [documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files) for more details.